# How to add columns to a monet.frame?

Tags: r, monetdb

How do I add columns to a `monet.frame`-object?

E.g. if I want to add a simple row ID to a `monet.frame` called  `data`, I could achieve that by doing something like:

```
from <- gsub("^SELECT(.)+FROM", "", data$query)
addid_query <- gsub("data", from, 
                    "SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id FROM data"
attr(data, "query") <- addidquery
```

but there must be a less hacky way. 
If you do it in the way given above, the newly created `id`-column does not show up when you do `str(data)` or `names(data)`, for example, because that info is not updated when the underlying database changes --- it is generated when `data` is initialized, not at the point where these acessor functions are called. It does show up when accessing rows of `data` directly because then the query gets executed as written.

Is stuff like the above still safe to do?

More generally, I need to do things with my `monet.frame` that are beyond the functionality that's available in the package and would be interested to know how to run more general SQL-queries on a `monet.frame`, similar to what `dplyr`'s `sql()`-function allows. I'd appreciate any pointers in that regard -- would I have to use `dbSendQuery` etc. and convert the result of that into a new `monet.frame`, for example? How?

---

EDIT:

NEVERMIND, should have read the manual more closely, I didn't see that `monet.frame` accepts strings that can be interpreted as SQL queries as well as table names that are already in the DB.

This is how I would do it now:

```
#' Apply general SQL queries to a monet.frame object and return the 
#' result in a new monet.frame.
#' 
#' @param data a \code{monet.frame} object
#' @param query an SQL query, using "_DATA_" as the placeholder for the
#'     name of the table underlying the \code{data}-object.
transform.monet.frame <- function(data, query){
    nm <- paste(sample(letters, 15, rep=TRUE), collapse="")
    query <- gsub("_DATA_", paste("(", attr(data, "query"), ") AS", nm), query) 
    monet.frame(attr(data, "conn"), query)
}

newdata <- transform(data, 
                 "SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id FROM _DATA_")
```

---

EDIT 2: This will break if applied to a `monet.frame` that was created by `transform.monet.frame` with a query involving ORDER, LIMIT or OFFSET statements.